# XmlSerializer.Deserialize uses for deserialization is not the type that is defined in the class field?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I ran into the problem: when XmlSerializer.Deserialize does not work correctly, or I do not understand how it works.

Class pastebin https://pastebin.com/FBvD2q5L

I have a class, and a xml document. I'm expecting deserialization to pass without problems, but I'm confronted with the fact that the fields of the capacities and hardlimit in the CapacityKey class are recognized as a ushort.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(licFile));

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filepath);
var license = (licFile)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

reader.Close();
reader.Dispose();
```

**[OverflowException: The value was unacceptably small or unacceptably large for UInt16.]
System.UInt16.Parse (String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)**

Which is strange because I specify the data type of UInt64, and I try to put only 4700000.

```
private UInt64 capacityField;
private UInt64 hardLimitField;
```

part of xml doc

```
<capacityKey id="CXC4031004">
    <description>EvoC 8000/RNC User Capacity HWAC</description>
    <start>2018-02-12</start>
    <noStop/>
    <capacity>4700000</capacity>
    <hardLimit>4700000</hardLimit>
</capacityKey>
```

If you type 4700 in your document instead of 4700000, then deserialization will be fine. This value is included in the limitations of the ushort.

```
license.body.SWLT.fingerprint.capacityKey[0].hardLimit  4700    ushort
```

But I do not need a ushort. What can be done ?

Comment: Can you add also the licFile type declaration ?

Comment: I have a link to it at the beginning of the question https://pastebin.com/FBvD2q5L

Comment: Just tried to deserialise the fragment of xml with the implementation you posted and it's working as expected.

Comment: indeed, everything is working on my home PC, but on the working PC and on the server the situation, as I described. What could be the reason?

Comment: working in consle app, and not worked on webserver iis/iisexpress